# Efficient way to substitute repeating np.vstack in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241401/is-there-an-academic-name-for-this-one-polyline-shape/3242064#3242064) in python.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,0,0])
for r in range(3):
    x = np.vstack((x, np.array([-r, r, -r])))
```

`x` gets this value

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  1, -1],
       [-2,  2, -2]])
```

I am concerned the runtime efficiency about the repeating `np.vstack`. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a list of arrays or lists, and apply `np.array` (or `vstack`) to that once:

```
In [598]: np.array([[-r,r,-r] for r in [0,0,1,2]])                                                    
Out[598]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  1, -1],
       [-2,  2, -2]])
```

But if the column pattern is consistent, broadcasting two arrays against each other will be faster

```
In [599]: np.array([-1,1,-1])*np.array([0,0,1,2])[:,None]                                             
Out[599]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  1, -1],
       [-2,  2, -2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) as  following:

- First create a block which you are currently doing inside the for loop
- Finally, vertically stack a row of zeros using `np.vstack` to get the final desired answer

---

```
import numpy as np

size = 3
sign = np.ones(3)*((-1)**np.arange(1, size+1)) # General sign array of repeating -1, 1

A = np.ones((size, size), int)
B = np.arange(0, size) * A
B = sign * np.block([B.T])         

# array([[ 0,  0,  0],
#        [ -1, 1, -1],
#        [ -2, 2, -2]])

answer = np.vstack([B[0], B])

# array([[ 0,  0,  0],
#        [ 0,  0,  0],
#        [ -1, 1, -1],
#        [ -2, 2, -2]])
```

Comment: The second column needs to be positive.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thanks again. I made it more genera now. Only size needs to be specified

Answer (score 1):

Would it be useful to use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)?

```
 N = 3
 A = np.array([[0, *range(0, -N, -1)]]).T
 B = np.tile(A, (1, N))
 B[:,1] = -B[:,1]
```

The first line sets the expected number of rows after the first row of zeroes.  The second creates a NumPy array by creating an initial value of 0, followed by the linear sequence of 0, -1, -2, up to `-N + 1`.  Note the use of the splat operator which unpacks the `range` object and creates elements in an individual list.  These are concatenated with the first value of 0, and we create a 2D NumPy array that is a column vector.  The third line tiles this vector N times horizontally to get the desired output.  Finally the fourth line negates the second column to get your desired output

## Example Run

```
In [175]: N = 3

In [176]: A = np.array([[0, *range(0, -N, -1)]]).T

In [177]: B = np.tile(A, (1, N))

In [178]: B[:,1] = -B[:,1]

In [178]: B
Out[178]:
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  1, -1],
       [-2,  2, -2]])
```

Comment: It's always nice to have alternate approaches. +1